# Django - console.EmailBackend - Show only text mails

Tags: python, django, email

For a django app, we are sending both text & html mails. For development, I am using console backend.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

This sends both text and html mails to console. Since html mails are ~500 lines, it is spamming the console.

I just need to check whether all variables are rendering properly or not. So, is there are way to send only text mails to console but not html mails?

Comment: yes, by adding an if condition to your code

Comment: You could subclass the console backend ([code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.8/django/core/mail/backends/console.py#L11)) and customize the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, you have to override the e-mail back-end to customise its behaviour in the desired way.

A minimal example could be something like that:

```
from django.core.mail.backends.console import EmailBackend
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage, EmailMultiAlternatives


class ConsoleEMailBackEnd(EmailBackend):
    """
    Subclass of Django `EmailBackend` that prints only
    `Content-Type: text/plain` alternative
    """

    def write_message(self, message: EmailMessage) -> None:
        """Override method to discard non-`text/plain` content-types"""
        if isinstance(message, EmailMultiAlternatives):
            message.alternatives = None
       super().write_message(message)
```

And of course, you declare your custom back-end in your settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'path_to_your.backends.ConsoleEMailBackEnd'
```